# fadeToggle() to CSS3 effect?

Tags: jquery, css

Is there a CSS3 equivalent to `.fadeToggle()` in jQuery?

I was googling around after seeing that my jq code didn't run the smoothest on mobile devices, and wanted to transform my already existing code into CSS3 animations (parts of it).

In my code below, it calls `.fadeToggle()` towards the bottom. I read an article saying it was possible to call CSS3 effects via jQuery: http://awardwinningfjords.com/2011/05/06/trigger-css3-animations-with-jquery.html

```
$(function () {
    function a(a) {
        a.each(function () {
            var b, c;
            a = $(this);
            b = a.find("a.toggle");
            c = a.find("div");
            b.click(function (a) {
                a.preventDefault();
                c.stop(false, true).slideToggle(300);
            });
        });
    }
    a($("div.container"));
});
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".toggle_overlay").click(function () {
        $(".widget_overlay").fadeToggle();
    });
});
```

Is there a CSS3 equivalent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The effect you are creating (clicking a `div` shows/hides it) isn't possible with purely CSS. There isn't any way to bind click events like that (well, unless you count the `:focus` pseudo class on input fields).

However, the CSS transition would function if you used JQuery to toggle a class (`.active`, for example). [JSFiddle here.](http://jsfiddle.net/qBaYk/1/) However, this is actually not such a good way to handle fading in and out, since JQuery does a lot of work behind the scenes to handle different browsers and their specific implementations of `opacity`. But, if you were doing something like changing the width of a `div`, it's great, because it lets you keep all your styling in the CSS and the logic contained to the Javascript.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use a [transtition](http://www.w3schools.com/css3/css3_transitions.asp), see [here for a jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/L4HSR/2/) showing it in action

Comment: That option requires you use a pseudo class to trigger the animation. There is no way to do that via clicking though.

Comment: You asked for a CSS3 equivalent of fadeToggle, not of click then fadeToggle... There is no CSS equivalent of click, that event will have to be handled by javascript. FYI Have updated fiddle to be closer to fadeToggle.

Comment: You could  try and see if a combination of the 2 works: http://jsfiddle.net/L4HSR/3/

Answer (score 1):

You can emulate a click without JavaScript. Just change the pseudo-class from hover to focus. You need to add a tabindex so the element can hold focus.

```
    <div id="cf">
    <img class="bottom" tabindex="2" src="http://www.w3schools.com/css/klematis.jpg" />
    </div>
```

Then you just use :focus because it requires a click or tap:

```
    #cf img:focus {
    opacity:0; 
    }
```

Here's my (changed) fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Lc84p3cw/
Of course it works backwards, you click it and it fades out, onblur it reappears...